# have problem with primeNG when using <p-captcha > tag

Tags: module, primeng, recaptcha, captcha, angular16

i'm using angular 16.0.0 and primeng 16 .
trying to add google recaptcha v3 to my project. in primeng website guide it seems to easy but after add

" import {CaptchaModule} from 'primeng/captcha'; "

to my "app.module.ts" file , angular gives an error :
" Cannot find module 'primeng/captcha' or its corresponding type declarations. "
and so can't use  tag .

looking for a solution but a lot of references using bootstrap !
tried to  install  package  'primeng/captcha'  but found nothing , for another test i make captcha folder on primeng folder and added older version of primeng Captcha files to that but didn't answer like the others.
another prefer packages makes no change as result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `p-captcha` component was removed from v15

For more detail please check:

[issue #12781](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/12781)

[commit #cc035e4](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/cc035e414efa3091914ffc0adf057ecca8afbfd0)